# Mysql database in a symlink-ed directory gives ERROR 1005 (errorno: 13)

Tags: mysql, permissions

I've the need to put my database outside the default datadir of mysql.

To achieve that I followed the [symlink guidance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/symbolic-links.html) in the mysql documentation.

However when I `use` the db if I try to create a table I'm greeted with:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test' (errno: 13)

In my search for solutions I already read [Can I use symlink or data directory for ARCHIVE MySQL tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33047/can-i-use-symlink-or-data-directory-for-archive-mysql-tables) and [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5977/39160) which didn't apply for my context.

At the moment my data dir looks like this with `ls -Ll`

```
server:/var/lib/mysql# ls -Ll
total 28800
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root         0 Jan 26 00:37 debian-5.5.flag
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    25088 Feb  8  2005 ib_arch_log_0000000000
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 18874368 May 31 15:21 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  5242880 May 31 15:21 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  5242880 Feb  8  2005 ib_logfile1
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql     4096 Jan 26 00:37 mysql
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root         0 May 29 00:01 so
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql     4096 May 28 22:48 so2
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql      4096 May 31 14:34 symlink
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql     4096 Apr 20  2013 test
```

The two symlinks are created with the command

```
ln -s /mnt/nas/se/data/mysql/ so
```

I `chown` the symlinks to mysql:mysql as well as in the directory it self. For the `symlink` directory that worked (that is on an ext3 fs) but for the `so` one (that is on a nas over CIFS/SMB) I'm still out of luck.

I managed to enable NFS (ver 3) on the NAS (running BusyBox v1.1.1) and mounted that as well. I synced the UID for the mysql account on the server and the client. Unfortunately the result is the same for `ls -Ll`

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root  rene      4096 May 31 16:51 sonfs
```

and for `ls -l`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root         8 Jun  1 00:26 sonfs -> /mnt/nfs
```

I did `su mysql` and tried to cp a file to those symlinked directories and that worked which made me assume on the OS level the permissions are OK.

Within mysql I granted root all permissions to the so and the symlink database.

I'm not sure if I the problem I face is something I misconfigured at the Debian OS level or within mysql itself.

Can someone point out to me what diagnosis I need to do and which steps need to be taken to be able to create tables that get stored in those symlinked directories?

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -Ll` in that directory, just to be sure? Also what filesystem is it and what mount options do you have?

Comment: @Mat you're on to something...Now it shows root as owner and group...

Comment: As root, `cd so` then `chown mysql:mysql .`. If that doesn't work, will need to know what filesystem you're using.

Comment: @Mat the `symlink` db now works, that is on the same box, the filesystem is ext3. The `so` one is on my nas and that is CIFS/SMB.

Comment: Urgh. No idea if that can work with SMB. Is NFS not an option on your NAS? (Better chances of that working, but you'll need someone who actually knows MySQL to tell you if that's safe.)

Comment: @Mat Yes, NFS is possible but I have to enable it. The mysql stuff should work if I use myisam and have a read-only/single user approach, if I understood the advice on that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this, basically by the advice given by Mat.

The first valueable tip was to use `ls -Ll` to show information  for the file the link references rather than for the link itself.

It is clear that the symlink should show the user (and group) mysql is using.

When mouting (in this case the cifs type) I first used

```
mount -t cifs //nas01/myshare /mnt/nas -o user=nasuser
```

where I should have used

```
mount -t cifs //nas01/myshare /mnt/nas -o user=nasuser,uid=mysql,gid=mysql
```

This resolved the errorno: 13 because `ls -Ll` now showed mysql as owner and group for the symlinked directory.