# mysql database under symlinked directory: ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './<dbname>/' (errno: 13)

Tags: mysql-5.5

I'm using mysql 5.5 on an ubuntu linux server.
I need to move a database from its current location (under /var/lib/mysql) to a disk with more space, so I attempted to move the directory and create a symlink to the new location.  When I do this, I get

```
ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './<dbname>/' (errno: 13)
```

when I attempt to `show tables` after starting mysql again.  **The error goes away if I move the database directory back to its original location.** (But, I need to move to a larger disk, so I've got to figure this out somehow)

I've looked around on this site and google; The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/symbolic-links.html) and the accepted answer to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33047/can-i-use-symlink-or-data-directory-for-archive-mysql-tables) indicates what I'm doing should work (I'm attempting to use option 3 from the accepted answer).

So, is this still supported?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Here's some additional information to jumpstart things:

- when I run `ls -lL /var/lib/mysql` all the files are owned by mysql (user & group)
- I've also changed ownership of the actual symlink to mysql:mysql (due to comments on [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66325/mysql-database-in-a-symlink-ed-directory-gives-error-1005-errorno-13))
- Both filesystems are on local disks (ext4)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the ubuntu mysql package uses apparmor.  I found a github blog entry (no longer available a/o Oct 2019) describing my scenario and the steps to fix it, summarized below:

> Here's the gotcha: Ubuntu comes with AppArmor. AppArmor's security model is to bind access control attributes to programs rather than to users. In my /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld file I've made these changes:
>
> ```
>  # I disabled these two lines;
>  # Comments indicate you don't need to
>  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
>  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
>  # Added these two lines
>  /example_ssd_partition/mysql/data r,
>  /example_ssd_partition/mysql/data/** rwk,
> ```

Comment: (1) Don't forget to restart  apparmor after you edited  /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld file `# service apparmor restart` (2) You don't have to disable original /var/lib/mysql/ lines, just add those for new location under link.